# Deserializing JSON array with Unity JsonUtility fails to get serialized values

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to deserialize card information from a JSON to be used in a Unity game, but it's not working quite right. I've tested the classes I'm trying to deserialize to, and I can manually create objects for them, but the deserializer doesn't create them correctly.

When I run the deserializing logic, the resulting array is the correct size, but none of the `Cost` or `Name` fields of the cards fill in and I'm left with an array of uninitialized `Card` objects.

The relevant code I have is as follows:

The file where we deserialize, Game.cs:

```
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;
public class Game {

    private CardsCollection allCards;    

    private void LoadJson()
    {
        ...
        // Find the path to our JSON file
        // Save the path as "path"

        // I have verified this line gets the correct json data as a string
        string json = File.ReadAllText(path); 

        // Convert the json string into a deserialized array of objects
        // using the CardsCollection wrapper
        allCards = JsonUtility.FromJson<CardsCollection>(json);
    }

}
```

The Card object file, Card.cs:

```
using System;
[Serializable]
public class Card
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Cost    { get; set; }

    public Card(string Name, int Cost)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Cost = Cost;
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class CardsCollection
{
    public Card[] cards;
}
```

And finally the JSON itself:

```
{
    "cards": [
        {
            "Name": "copper",
            "Cost": 0
        },
        {
            "Name": "silver",
            "Cost": 3
        },
        {
            "Name": "gold",
            "Cost": 6
        },
        {
            "Name": "curse",
            "Cost": 0
        },
        {
            "Name": "estate",
            "Cost": 2
        },
        {
            "Name": "duchy",
            "Cost": 5
        },
        {
            "Name": "province",
            "Cost": 8
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Is `Cards` exactly as is ? Or is there more content in that class ? Such as base classes

Comment: The above is the exact content of the `Cards` file, nothing extra, nothing missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Json serialization can only handle fields (see supported types https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JSONSerialization.html) but your Name and Cost look like properties [What is the difference between a field and a property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295104/what-is-the-difference-between-a-field-and-a-property)

Since they are marked public and can be accessed directly anyway I would just remove the {get; set}

Comment: Yep that's fixed it. I had no idea adding the getter/setter part would fundamentally alter the variable, thanks!